# Can I stack implicit types somehow?

Tags: coq

near the top of a .v file, I currently have something like

```
Implicit Types N: T1.
Implicit Types V: T2.
Implicit Types O: T3.
.....
```

this might be a trivial question, but can I condense these lines into one implicit types declaration if T1 T2 T3 are distinct? the fact that I have to repeat the command 3 times is annoying me lol. I looked on [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/extensions/implicit-arguments.html) and didn't see syntax for this, but I figured I would check.

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one

```
Implicit Types (N: T1)(V: T2)(O: T3).
```